# A way to export bezier curve with "bevel" (generated mesh) to a fbx mesh?

Tags: mesh, export, bezier-curves, .fbx, unreal-engine

Im trying to export a bezier curve to use in a game engine but it doesnt automatically convert the curve to a mesh and fails the export. At the moment I have to manually convert it to a mesh and then I lose the ability to rapidly test out different shapes on my curve.

[image]

Is there a way to automatically convert bezier curves to a meshes on export?

Comment: Hello, please show your export settings. It should automatically convert bezier curves to meshes

Comment: @Gorgious Ah, export "Other" wasn't checked, my mistake! Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to enable "Other" in the export properties.

[image]